# How to weight in full-text search

Tags: full-text-search, containstable

I want to search on a phrase, for example "search preference".  I want to return the phrase itself as most heavily weighted.
Next I would want to return "search" and/or "preference".

And, in lowest ranking, I would want "searching" or "searches" or "preferences".  I don't know what to put for weights in the IsAbout.

```
'ISABOUT(  
  "search preference" weight(.9),   
  "search" weight(.5),   
  "preference" weight(.5),   
  "search`*`" weight(.1),   
  "preference`*`" weight(.1)  
)'
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I put in a vote to delete my answer, because I discovered I was more ignorant that I thought about this topic.  I suggest adding a tag for 'sql-server'.  Happy hunting!